# Calendar event is getting added but notification is not coming

Tags: android, notifications, android-calendar

I am trying to add calendar event. It's getting added to native calendar but notification is not coming. Here is my code.

```
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+(2*60*1000);
        long endTime = startTime + (5*60*1000);

        ContentResolver cr1 = this.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startTime);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTime);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,"ATPI");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Calendar Event Description");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
        cr1.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I am testing the above code with Samsung Galaxy Nexus(OS 4.2.1).
Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't fire any Notification from your code.

Take a look at this Training in Android's developers: [Notifying the User](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I add any event manually in native calnedar, by default reminder has been set as notification. But when I add it programatically, reminder is not getting added hence notification is not coming. Can you please tell me how can I set the reminder through code?